# yajra/laravel-datatables search is not working with laravel 5.4

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datatables, laravel-5.4

I have used **yajra/laravel-datatables** to create data grid list. I have used joins to retrieve information as per requirement.

**Here is join code**

```
$inquiryInvoice = DB::table('inquiry_invoice')->select('inquiry_invoice.*',DB::raw('CONCAT(inquiry_personal.first_name, " ", inquiry_personal.middle_name, " ", inquiry_personal.last_name) AS full_name'), 'inquiry_personal.id as inquiry_personal_id','branches.branch_name',DB::raw('CONCAT(users.first_name, " ", users.last_name) AS user_full_name'), DB::raw('CONCAT(counselor.first_name, " ", counselor.last_name) AS counselor_full_name'), 'inquiry_counselor.user_id as inquiry_counselor_user_id','inquiry_master.workflow_id',DB::raw(' "invoice" AS type'))
                ->join('inquiry_master', 'inquiry_master.id', '=', 'inquiry_invoice.inquiry_id')
                ->join('inquiry_personal', 'inquiry_master.id', '=', 'inquiry_personal.inquiry_id')
                ->join('branches', 'inquiry_master.branch_id', '=', 'branches.id')
                ->join('users', 'inquiry_master.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                ->leftJoin('inquiry_counselor', 'inquiry_master.id', '=', 'inquiry_counselor.inquiry_id')
                ->leftJoin('users as counselor', 'inquiry_counselor.user_id', '=', 'counselor.id');
```

**Here is code for assign `Datatables`**

```
return Datatables::of($inquiryInvoice)
            ->escapeColumns([])
            ->make(true);
```

**Here is jQuery code**

```
$dataTable = $('#data-table').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            Filter: true,
            url:'{!! url("transaction_any_data") !!}',
            columns: [
                { data: 'full_name', name: 'full_name' },
                { data: 'branch_name', name: 'branch_name' },
                { data: 'user_full_name', name: 'user_full_name' },
                { data: 'counselor_full_name', name: 'counselor_full_name' }
            ]
        });
```

Now when i try to search something it is giving me **alert** with **error**
Here is an error message,
[image]

Now i want to know,

**how can i quick search using `JOIN` and `CONCAT` columns?**

**Is there specific way to do this?**

please suggest me the best way...

Comment: This has nothing to do with DataTables. You have a mistake in your SQL query, just like the error message says.

Comment: @Jerodev, it is not SQL error, because when i run query in mysql it works well and return result. issue is DataTables search on in database table's column, not in concated column

Answer (score 2):

With Laravel DataTables you need to include table name in the [`columns.name`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.name) option when you use two or more tables with ambiguous names.

Since `full_name` is ambiguous name you need to change it to `inquiry_invoice.full_name`.

For example:

```
$dataTable = $('#data-table').DataTable({
   processing: true,
   serverSide: true,
   url:'{!! url("transaction_any_data") !!}',
   columns: [
      { data: 'full_name', name: 'inquiry_invoice.full_name' },
      { data: 'branch_name', name: 'branch_name' },
      { data: 'user_full_name', name: 'user_full_name' },
      { data: 'counselor_full_name', name: 'counselor_full_name' }
   ]
});
```

Another problem is that you need to use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE` to search columns produced with `CONCAT`. You need to use [`filterColumn()`](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/filter-column) method to produce custom search clause for last three columns.

For example (untested):

```
return Datatables::of($inquiryInvoice)
        ->escapeColumns([])
        ->filterColumn('branch_name', function($query, $keyword) {
            $query->havingRaw('LOWER(branch_name) LIKE ?', ["%{$keyword}%"]);
        })
        ->filterColumn('user_full_name', function($query, $keyword) {
            $query->havingRaw('LOWER(user_full_name) LIKE ?', ["%{$keyword}%"]);
        })
        ->filterColumn('counselor_full_name', function($query, $keyword) {
            $query->havingRaw('LOWER(counselor_full_name) LIKE ?', ["%{$keyword}%"]);
        })
        ->make(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

It simply doesn't work with POST. Try using GET as Http Method. (At least for Laravel 5.5 and 5.6)

Answer (score -2):

You should be update your PHP version with PHP 7.0 or greater then it'll work fine.

Comment: I have my PHP version 7.1.9 and mysql version 5.7.19